# Average value of a function over a square and quarter of cirle

Tags: integration

Can we guess whether the average value over a square is larger than that over quarter of a circle , or not ?

for example , can we guess (before calculating) if the average value of 
$$f(x,y)=xy$$
over the square 
$$ 0\leq x\leq1$$ $$ 0\leq y\leq1$$
is larger than the average value of the same function over the **first quadrant** of  the unit circle 
$$x^2+y^2\leq1 $$
Or Can we find the reason for which the avg value over the square is larger ?!

Comment: We sure can guess, but our guess might turn out to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider  the set of all functions such that $f(x,y) \ge 0$ $\quad$ yes you can guess before looking at the function. Area of square > area of first quadrant.
so $\int_{square} f(x,y) d\mu \ge \int_{quadrant} f(x,y) d\mu $

Other than that you would have to look at the function before making the guess.

Comment: but to get the average value , we will divide by the area ...Are we sure that after dividing by the area , the inequality is maintained ? ..I think it depends how much is the integration over the square is larger ...So we can not guess

$$\frac{1}{1*1} \int_{square} f(x,y) d\mu \ge  \frac{1}{\pi/4} \int_{quadrant} f(x,y) d\mu$$

Comment: I think is the way you defined average. The result should be divided by the size of the space where integration is defined and that's the way it is defined in probability theory.

Comment: so in your case, you are comparing averages from two different regions.